# R: Create new column based list of values from a multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column (T/F) based on any value from a list being present in multiple columns. For this example, I'm using mtcars for my example, searching for two values in two columns, but my actual challenge is many values in many columns.

I have a successful filter using `filter_at()` included below, but I've been unable to apply that logic to a mutate:

```
# there are 7 cars with 6 cyl
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 6)

# there are 2 cars with 19.2 mpg, one with 6 cyl, one with 8
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg == 19.2)

# there are 8 rows with either.
# these are the rows I want as TRUE
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg == 19.2 | cyl == 6)

# set the cols to look at
mtcars_cols <- mtcars %>% 
  select(matches('^(mp|cy)')) %>% names()

# set the values to look at
mtcars_numbs <- c(19.2, 6)

# result is 8 vars with either value in either col.
# this is a successful filter of the data
out1 <- mtcars %>% 
    filter_at(vars(mtcars_cols), any_vars(
        . %in% mtcars_numbs
        )
      )

# shows set with all 6 cyl, plus one 8cyl 21.9 mpg
out1 %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl)

# This attempts to apply the filter list to the cols,
# but I only get 6 rows as True
# I tried to change == to %in& but that results in an error
out2 <- mtcars %>%
    mutate(
      myset = rowSums(select(., mtcars_cols) == mtcars_numbs) > 0
    )

# only 6 rows returned
out2 %>% 
  filter(myset == T)
```

I'm not sure why the two rows are skipped. I *think* it might be the use of `rowSums` that is aggregating those two rows in some way.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to do the corresponding checks, it may be better to use `map2`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(purrr)
 map2_df(mtcars_cols, mtcars_numbs, ~ 
       mtcars %>%
           filter(!! rlang::sym(.x) == .y)) %>%
     distinct
```

NOTE: Doing the comparison (`==`) with floating point numbers can get into trouble as the precision can vary and result in FALSE

---

Also, note that `==` works only when when either the `lhs` and `rhs` elements have the same length or the `rhs` vector is of `length` 1 (here the recycling happens).  If the `length` is greater than 1 and not equal to length of lhs vector, then the recycling would be comparing in the column order.

We can `rep`licate to make the lengths equal and now it should work

```
mtcars %>%
 mutate(
   myset = rowSums(select(., mtcars_cols) == mtcars_numbs[col(select(., mtcars_cols))]) > 0
   ) %>% pull(myset) %>% sum
#[1] 8
```

In the above code `select` is used twice for better understanding.  Otherwise, we can also use `rep`

```
mtcars %>%
 mutate(
   myset = rowSums(select(., mtcars_cols) == rep(mtcars_numbs, each = n())) > 0
    ) %>% 
   pull(myset) %>%
   sum
#[1] 8
```

Comment: Good point about floating point numbers, though I'm searching for strings in my real dataset instead of numbers ... I should've used a different example data set. I'll give these a whirl today and let you know. Another thought I had was to build a function to loop through a list of columns for the values and set the answer with mutate.

Comment: OK, I admit I'm a little lost trying to apply the `map2` concepts to my data. I also feel like using mtcars and the floating point data is not really analogous to my actual challenge, so I have I have a very long explanation of what I'm after and what I have tried [at this published notebook](https://utdata.github.io/thcic-pudf/99-mutate-challenge.html). I'll add some edits above to reflect that.